# How to insert increasing date in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I have the following query, i need to insert start date in increasing order for e.g 01/01/1000, 01/02/1000, 01/03/1000,....

```
Insert into person_location(address,person,city,country,
  startdate,enddate,source) 
Select  distinct de.P_address,
  A.ID,
  de.P_city, 
  de.P_Country,
  to_date('01/01/1000','DD/MM/YYYY'),
  to_date('31/12/3999','DD/MM/YYYY'),
  de.source
from data_excel de, person A
where de.P_name in ( Select Distinct name from person)
and ID > 6571
```

Comment: What do you mean? Each ID has a start date one day (or month) later than the last? Hoe are `person` and `data_excel` linked - is your `in` supposed to be a join condition?

Comment: i have to compare the name from peron's table and insert in person_location. Data_excel has the name and address. Each person can have more than 1 address but id and start date is the primary key in the person_location table

Comment: Having date as primary is bad idea jus make it a number sequence

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a properly named and normalized database schema. The following is a rough layout. Note each table has a single primary key, named after the table with 'ID' appended. I think your questions will be answered by working with such a database schema.

Person table:

```
PersonID long not null primary key    
FirstName varchar255 not null
MiddleName varchar255 nullable
Lastname varchar255 not null
```

PersonAddress table:

```
PersonAddressID long not null primary key
PersonID long not null foreign key to the Person table  ((note: not unique, since a person may have more than one address))
StreetAddress varchar255 not null
CityID long not null foreign key to the City table
CountryID long not null foreign key to the Country table
StartDate Date not null  //when the person first moved to this address
EndDate Date nullable //when the person left this address. Null if still lives there
```

City table:

```
CityID long not null primary key
Name varchar255 not null, unique
```

Country table:

```
CountryID long not null primary key
Name varchar255 not null, unique
```

Comment: `long` and `varchar255`? Hopefully you mean `number` (or some variant) and `varchar2(<size>)`, and are mixing up your databases. `long` is a deprecated large character holder. Also not sure how this really helps with the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Craete a sequence, e.g.:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE start_Date_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE  NOCYCLE;
```

And then create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_location_insert
   BEFORE INSERT ON person_location

   BEGIN
     :new.startdate := ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1000','DD/MM/YYYY'), start_Date_seq.nextval);
END;
```